# Insert Subquery in Select Query

Tags: mysql

I have a "Groups" table and a "Participants" table. Now I need to insert one Participant for each Group. How would I automate this?

```
INSERT INTO "Participants" ("Name", "FirstName", "GroupID") VALUES ("GENERIC", "GENERIC", GroupID)
```

This Insert should be called for each Group in the Groups table, and the "GroupID" replaced with the corresponding ID.

Would this work with a subquery?

Thanks,
martin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

INSERT INTO SELECT...

```
INSERT INTO
    Participants
(
    Name,
    FirstName,
    GroupID
)
SELECT
    'GENERIC',
    'GENERIC',
    GroupID
FROM
    Groups
```

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO `Participants`
SELECT ("Name", "FirstName", `group_id`)
FROM `Group`
```