# mysql merge duplicate records in table

Tags: php, mysql

how can i get final table? I want to merge so that if it compares and there is an empty column in a record, it fills it up with the latter value. The rules are that storetype should appear only once for each user

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're grouping by `username` and `storetype`. Try running this:

```
select min(id), username, min(filename), min(date), min(desc), storetype,
    min(password), min(email), min(ftp)
from table1
group by username, storetype
```

Note, of course, this will work in the case you really have the data as you displayed in your screenshot, i.e., only 1 non-null value per each `username` and `storetype` pair in each column but the `id` column. In that case, the `id` column, it looks like you chose the minimum, so the query will result in that too.

Comment: thanks. working at it now. How do i put the results in another table(Final)?

Comment: @karto There are many questions with info on how to do that, such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304750/insert-subquery-in-select-query)

Comment: getting happy with this.:-) now seeing the query nicely displayed. Now i will look at how to populate it in a new table

Comment: @karto If this did the trick, then I wonder why you selected another answer as the correct one.

Comment: i had selected that earlier but realised this was more optimzed. thanks for the corrections. +1

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the dirtiest piece of code I've ever done :)... and I won't even recommend it if you have more than few hundreds of records to process. Let me know as I wasn't able to check it on IDE.

```
<?php

  $query = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE 1';
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  if ($result){
      while ($result=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
         $data[] = $row;
     }
  }

  // 

  if (isset($data)){
     $x=0;
     $y=0;
     $missingColumn = array();

     while ($x < count($data)){
        foreach ($data[$x] as $key=>$value){
            if (empty($value)){
               $missingColumn[$y][] = $key;
            } else {
               $output[$y][] = $value;
            }  
        }
        if ($missingColumn[$y]){
           $rowComplete = FALSE;
           $yetToBeCompleted = count($missingColumn[$y]);
           while (!$rowComplete && $x<count($data)){
              $x++;
              foreach ($missingColumn as $value){
                 if ($data[$x][$value] <> ''){
                    $output[$y][$value] = $data[$x][$value];
                    $yetToBeCompleted--;
                 }  
              }
              if (0 == $yetToBeCompleted){
                 $y++;
                 break;
                 //$rowComplete = TRUE;
              }
           }
           $y++;          

        } else {
          $y++;
          $x++;
        }
     }
  }


?>
```

Comment: maybe merge and delete duplicate records

Comment: thanks. can i get a table 'final' created and populated as shown?

Comment: If you mean eliminating columns with empty value, that shouldn't be called "merged". how about the query above?

Comment: You can Add SELECT DISTINCT filename, date from table1 to get unique records.

Comment: Are you okay with using mysql+php?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not that versatile in mysql but without any difficult data alteration techniques, I don't think that's possible.

- Edit especially because in some coloums you take the most encountered value and replace the "merged" cell with that value

Comment: merge and delete duplicate records

Comment: You keep saying that, but how do you plan on merging them. What are you rules? It seems to me that you always have a sterotype? Maybe somehow figure out how to group by name and storetype and from that point grab columns as they come.

Comment: The rules are that storetype should appear only once

Comment: You should check out this thread. It maybe useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941116/merge-two-rows-in-sql